# WearOS and Android App connection issues?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm currently working on my first WearOS Project. For the beginning i just want to establish a connection between my WearOS app and a basic android app running on a phone.
For the testing i'm using my Pixel Watch 2 and my Pixel 7.

For testing the connection between the 2 devices i just wanted to count up a counter variable, but i'm encountering some weird issues in the testing.

When both apps are freshly installed from skretch i can count up the counter for one time (change it to value 1) when pressing the button on the WearOS app. However once this happened the counter doesent change anymore. Even if i reload the apps in Android Studio. It works only this one time when both apps are completly fresh installed. I already tried some debugging by logging, and after the first increasing of the counter the event listener on the phone app doesent get a event anymore.

This is my code for WearOS:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val dataViewModel: DataViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Initialisiere den DataClient, wenn noch nicht geschehen
        dataViewModel.initializeDataClient(this)

        setContent {
            WearApp("Android", dataViewModel)
        }
    }
}

class DataViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var dataClient: DataClient? = null
        private set

    fun initializeDataClient(context: Context) {
        if (dataClient == null) {
            dataClient = Wearable.getDataClient(context.applicationContext)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun WearApp(greetingName: String, dataViewModel: DataViewModel) {
    InnoLabCodeTheme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp)) // Füge Abstand hinzu
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                ForwardButton(dataViewModel)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp)) // Füge Abstand zwischen den Buttons hinzu
                BackButton(dataViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ForwardButton(dataViewModel: DataViewModel) {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            // Put the data item to the phone
            dataViewModel.dataClient?.putDataItem(createCounterUpdateDataItem())
            // Update the counter and display it
            // Log.d("ForwardButton clicked", "ForwardButton clicked")
            println("ForwardButton clicked")

        }
    ) {
        Text("Vorwärts")
    }
}

@Composable
fun BackButton(dataViewModel: DataViewModel) {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            dataViewModel.dataClient?.putDataItem(createCounterUpdateDataItem())
            println("BackButton clicked")
        }
    ) {
        Text("Zurück")
    }
}

private fun createCounterUpdateDataItem(): PutDataRequest {
    return PutDataRequest.create("/path").setUrgent()
}
```

And this is my code for the phone app:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var dataClient: DataClient? = null
    private var count = 0
    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Erstelle und verbinde den DataClient
        dataClient = Wearable.getDataClient(this)

        // Beispiel für das Empfangen von Daten
        dataClient?.addListener { dataEvents ->
            Log.d("Data Received", "Data received")
            for (event in dataEvents) {
                Log.d("Data Received", event.toString())
                // Check if the data item is from the WearOS app
                if (event.dataItem.uri.path == "/path") {
                    // Update the counter and display it
                    count++
                    updateCounter()
                }
            }
        }

        // Erstelle Textfeld um Text anzuzeigen
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        textView.text = count.toString()
    }

    private fun updateCounter() {
        runOnUiThread {
            textView.text = count.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in this code?

Thanks!

Tried to connect WearOS app with phone app but experienced some issues with connection.

Comment: Ok, I don't get much kotlin, so sorry if I interpreted it wrong... but seems to me that u r creating over and over that "/path" when ForwardButton is called... If that's the case: 1 it seems weird, because, I might be wrong again, but the datalayer is a key value "object", and u have only one entry; 2 - the listeners will only be called when u create/change/delete a value... so if you enter "/path" and then u enter "/path" again, the api will consider it the same, so it won't call the change listener... try to add a random string/other every time u tap the button, so the dataitem will change

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is missing adding data to your request, e.g:

```kotlin
var counter = 0
private fun createCounterUpdateDataItem(): PutDataRequest {
    return PutDataRequest.create("/path")
        .apply {
            dataMap.putInt("counter", counter++)
        }.setUrgent()
}
```

You can try running the [Datalayer](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/DataLayer) on your devices in order to see it working. [Here](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/5511ba61b96d57b7da2722e427397bf48085fc8d/DataLayer/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/datalayer/MainActivity.kt#L224) is where it sends the counter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast Response. The DataViewModell Class is defined in the WearOS Code abvove. I will try your solution, thank you:)

Comment: Update:
I changed the code how you recomended it.
But i still encounter the same problem. The value on the phone app changes to 1 and after that no data / event is recieved anymore. In the logs it looks like this:

`2024-01-15 20:26:32.424 17885-17885 Data Received`


so there is 1 event when it changes to 1 but no one after.

Comment: Does the [Datalayer](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/DataLayer) sample apps work on your devices?